# Are prime elements of R and R[x] the same?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $a$ is prime element of $R$, then can we say $a$ is also prime element of $R[x]$?

What about other direction? - if $a$ is prime element of $R[x]$ then is it prime element of $R$?

If $R$ and $R[x]$ are isomorphic $\implies$ what ever is in $R$ is that in $R[x]$?

I know that units and irreducibles in each other are the same

Regarding, if $a$ is prime element of $R$, then can we say $a$ is also prime element of $R[x]$:

My approach:

Let $a$ be prime in $R$ and not prime in $R[x]$
then $a \vert f(x)g(x); $

$a \nmid f(x)$

$a \nmid g(x)$ this implies
$f(x) = q_1(x)a+r_1(x)$ and $g(x) = q_2(x)a+r_2(x)$

As $r_1(x)$ and  $r_1(x)$ are not equal to zero

$deg(r_1(x)) < deg(a) \rightarrow contradiction \hspace{1mm}as\hspace{0.4 cm} deg(a) = 0$

Please correct me. I sense something wrong there.

Comment: Please check the formatting of your formulas, it is hard to read. What are the $;;;;;$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If $R$ is an integral domain then $x$ is a prime element of $R[x]$, but not even an element of $R$. Wikipedia contains [other examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element#Examples) of prime elements of polynomial rings which are clearly not even elements of the underlying ring.

To the rest of your question: If $R\cong R[x]$, then this does *not* mean $r\in  R[x]\to r\in R$ (this is how I interpreted your statement).

Comment: *For example $x$ is a prime element of $R[x]$...* No, not always. If it is, it implies that $R$ is an integral domain. If there was a pair of nonzero zero divisors $a,b$ with $ab=0$, then $(x-a)b\in (x)$ but neither $x-a$ nor $b$ is in $(x)$. But the main thrust of the solution about prime elements of $R[x]$ not even being in $R$ is what the OP needs the most.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you, this was enlightening. I hope my edit fixed it.

Comment: Yes, indeed it does patch things up.

Comment: can you pls elaborate? R is isomorphic to R[x]. So if an element has particular nature(property) in R , then will that nature(property) be carried / transfered to R[x]?